# can't install python modules using pip

Tags: package-management, python, 16.04, pip

I am trying to install python module "scrapy". I have pip 8.1 and python 3.4 installed . I have tried the following command in the terminal

```
sudo pip install scrapy
```

but i get this error 
[instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i3Rr.png)

I also tried installing via pycharm IDE . and i get the following error :

```
c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing python-dev, libffi-dev, libssl-dev, libxml2-dev, and libxslt1-dev packages. Once these are installed, `pip install scrapy` will work fine.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
sudo pip install scrapy
```

Comment: Worked :) But had to add sudo to second command

Comment: hey i am glad it worked.

Comment: hey i have tried installing another library called cx_freeze and same thing happened . it shows "failed building wheel for cx-Freeze". i tried the above solution. didn't work

Comment: have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107697/compiling-cx-freeze-under-ubuntu